# Script returns a wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering why I am getting a wrong value.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Return a question
    function show_question(id, answer) {
        // Check if the answer is correct
        $('.check_answer_' + id).click(function() {
            alert(id);
            if($('#quiz_answer_q' + id + '_a' + answer).is(':checked')) { 
                $('.quiz_confirmation_wrong').hide();
                $('.explanation_q'+ id +', .next_question_'+ id +', .quiz_confirmation_correct').show('clip');
                $(this).css({ 'pointer-events' : 'none', 'opacity': 0.5 })
            }
            else {
                $('.quiz_confirmation_correct').hide();
                $('.quiz_confirmation_wrong').show('clip');
            }
        });
        // Go to next question
        $('.next_question_'+ id).click(function() {
            if($('#quiz_answer_q'+ id +'_a'+ answer).is(':checked')) { 
                var i = id;
                i++;
                $('.quiz_confirmation').hide();
                $('.quiz_field_'+ id).hide();
                $('#q'+ i++ +', .check_answer_'+ i++).show('bounce', 1000);             
            }
        });
    }

    show_question(1, 1);
    show_question(2, 2);

});
```

As you see on the bottom of my code I am running the code twice with different parameters. The first time `alert(id)` returns **1**, which is correct. The second time it returns **3**, when it needs to be **2** as I specify it with the first parameter. So why is it returning 3 instead of 2?

**Update:**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuwb7wgm/)

Comment: Can you add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) showing the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code given. Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: What wrong answer are you getting? What would the right answer be? What HTML does this operator on? I bet the problem is your very heavy use of `i++`.

Comment: can you please put your html code here

Comment: @Styphon sure, it's updated.

Comment: @Quentin the wrong value is 3. The correct value should be 2. Please check the jsfiddle.

Comment: @SunilKumar sure, please find it on jsfiddle.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: But yes, it sounds like you shouldn't be incrementing `i` all the time.

Comment: @Quentin I was thinking that this must be the problem but how can I solve it?

Comment: @Quentin check Id of button button. your directily going to div 3 instead of div 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing write. you are incrementing wrongly please increment i one time while your are pressing next button.

```
$('#q'+ i +', .check_answer_'+ i++).show('bounce', 1000);
```

[I have update jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/yuwb7wgm/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the hero of my day!! :)